# Understanding particle scattering vs interaction

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, scattering, interactions

I have two questions to clarify what I am actually trying to ask through this question:

1. What is the difference between "interaction" and "scattering" in particle physics?
2. Does scattering of two particles lead to production of entirely different particles?

I am confused because the lecture note of my Particle Physics course says "Draw the Feynman diagram for the $K^-p$ scattering process leading to the production of $Σ^+.$"

Also, in the light of above two questions, what does $π^-p$ scattering process look like? Does it lead to production of new particles? I am simply confused how "scattering" can lead to production of entirely different particles.

Comment: Re (2), see, e.g., [Deep inelastic scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_inelastic_scattering)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between "interaction" and "scattering" in particle physics?

Scattering is an interaction, an interaction may not be a scattering, for example a decay of a particle to other particles.

All interactions of elementary particles are modeled  with [Feynman diagrams](https://www.quantumdiaries.org/2010/02/14/lets-draw-feynman-diagams/), which are an iconic representation of the integrals leading to numbers for cross sections and decays.

> Does scattering of two particles lead to production of entirely different particles?

The basic elementary  particles of the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) are the following.

[image: elem]

The quarks are the basic interacting content of hadrons ; Pions, kaons protons are bound states of quarks , and it is the complex interactions that have to be predicted by the models when they are scattered against each other.

electron positron scattering is elementary, and depending on the energy of the interaction due to special relativity the energy can turn to various end products from the particle table, while conserving the quantum numbers. At [LEP all hadrons](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0242)  were created and studied, in addition to leptons.

For hadrons on hadrons the basic interactions are quarks on quarks but the spectator (left out)quarks have to be taken into account for accuracy of calculations and the end products. [This link](http://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2002/feynman/examples.htm) has examples:

[image: Kp]